# Visiblity of data in my network (Encrypted Tunnels)

Tags: exit-relays, onion-routing, encryption, tunnel

My question is whether data about my addressed websites and me are visible/unencrypted within my network.
E.g. I want to access 'https://ixquick.com/' using the Tor browser. Is the request for ixquick or other information visible/unencrypted between my computer and my home router?

Am I correct when I say, the only connection, where the addressed website is even visible is between the exit node and the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its encrypted from your computer until it exits the exit node.